# Flex grid: Alternate left and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Using Flexbox**: I'd like to place a series of divs vertically down a containing div some left some right. Where each div L & R is 70% width of the container div. L div must be pinned to the left side of the container and R div is pinned to the right hand side of the container.

```
L
      R
L
L
      R
      R
      R
L
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a flex container that has `flex-direction: column`, then align each child item based on it's class with `align-self`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

div.left, div.right {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div.left {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: orange;
}

div.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `float:left` and `float:right` together with `:nth-child` selector

```css
div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  background: blue;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  L
</div>
<div>
  R
</div>
<div>
  L
</div>
<div>
  R
</div>
<div>
  L
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong question, I've just updated my question

Comment: @Rory well. then you can't use selectors. can you give different classes to the divs ? for example to L divs class `left` and to R divs class `right` ?