# Alternate left right divs with common div containing a line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've received an answer to a question I posted here [Flex grid: Alternate left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760179/flex-grid-alternate-left-and-right).

But my requirement has just changed and I'm struggling to get this one done.
As with the linked question I want L & R divs 70% of their container but now I require a line (dotted) at the end of each L & R div but the line must run 100% of the container. I got it working with floats left and right, but need it to be Flexbox, there's just so many variables and properties with Flexbox it's difficult to know where to start.

```
L
-------------
            R
-------------
            R
-------------
            R
-------------
L
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pseudo element `:after` to create the dotted border

I edited the snippet of the answer you provided

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

div.left,
div.right {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div.left {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

div.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
}

.column div::after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <div class="left">L</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: dotted;
}

div.left, div.right {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div.left {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: orange;
}

div.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="left">L</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="right">R</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="left">L</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting confused, thinking the hr had to be within the scope of the flexbox itself.